# jquery ui datepicker set default date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two text boxes , I want dates to be populated as 6 months back and 15 days ahead date from current date. I am able to select default date in datepicker , but not able to set the default date to text box

```
 $("#fromDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',defaultDate : '-6m' });
 $("#toDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',defaultDate: '+15d' });
```

Please find fiddle here : [datepickerIssue](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/L4gvh9wp/)

Thanks

Comment: you want to have the date already in the `input` tag before selecting the date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to  chain the `setDate` method call after your datepicker initialization and then use the usual relative notation of datepicker, for example to get the following 15 days or previous 6 months:

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).datepicker("setDate", "-6m");
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).datepicker("setDate", "+15d");
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/bhxuqonc/)**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should call datepicker()
and then call datepicker again to setDate with new Date().

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#datepicker1").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
   $("#datepicker2").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
})
```

In other case where you know what date you want to set as default date, you can place it in value of input element.

```
 <input type="text" id="datepicker2" value='21/01/2014'>
```